# Is there a way to start a task only when "await" happens?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Considering:

> "Only methods that return void, Task, or Task can be marked as async..."

If I need to invoke a logic or starting something only when the task is "awaited", in this case when the method `OnCompleted(Action continuation)` or  `UnsafeOnCompleted(Action continuation)` of `TaskAwaiter` implementation, somehow can I do it?

For example:

I need to mock some implementation that returns `Task<T>`, is this case my mock required to use and to continue in just one `Thread`, but in no way to manipulate the `SynchronizationContext`.

I know it's a very specific scenario, but is just for theory. Likewise there's the `Unwrap()` method, is there something like `Wrap(IAwaitable accessAwaiter)`?

If the `Task` only starts when the `await` is "awaited", it already solves my problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Your "mock" example doesn't make sense because asynchronous mocks do not need to complete their tasks in a particular thread.

Comment: I'm having some fun with Ix (using the `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`), I saw the implementation of `ToAsyncEnumerable` and every time a `MoveNext` is used a new task is created using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. So, I was thinking of using my own "awaiter", but apparently I will not be able to do it, because that would change the interface. The most I can do is create a custom implementation of `ToAsynEnumerable` to use with a `TaskFactory` or something like it. Any other suggestion?

Comment: So you're trying to avoid the `StartNew` in your unit tests? You could write your own extension method and `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` implementation. Not sure if it's really worth micro-optimizing unit tests, though.

Comment: Actually my units tests are only for a theoretical purpose, but I really will try something different, writing my own extension method (in this case to use in a real scenario). Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm still confused. :) I have the feeling that there's a better solution, if I could understood the use case better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But you can write your own awaiter that you can mock, if you *really* need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not advise doing this, but yes you can start a `Task` when an await happens.

Here is a toy example that, again, *I do not advise using:*

```
public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this TimeSpan timeSpan) 
{ 
    return Task.Delay(timeSpan).GetAwaiter();
}
```

Usage:

```
await TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
```

Similar to how a `foreach` loop expands to code that calls `GetEnumerator()` on the enumerable, `await <expression>` is an expression that expands to something that calls `(<expression>).GetAwaiter()` with a bunch of other magic to make continuations happen.

#### Edit

If all you want is to `await` a `Task` that may not yet be started, starting it if it has not yet started, you can simply use this:

```
public static Task EnsureStarted(this Task task)
{
    if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
    {
        try
        {
            task.Start();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
    }
    return task;
}
```

And use like so:

```
await task.EnsureStarted();
```

Comment: Yeah cool, I really could handle the start of the `Task` with this, but in my case the method needs to return a `Task`, so I cannot return something different that would use a custom GetAwaiter method, when the "await" happens..

Comment: Yeah, for most of scenarios would work perfectly, but sounds like a "hack", every method that returns that `Task` I'll need to call this extension. The main objective would be to encapsulate the behavior, not influencing who will using. This gave me some ideas, if I implement a concept to “jumping the trampoline” maybe I'll get to my goal in another way. Thanks!